# E488 trailing characters error while trying to open a file in VIM

Tags: vim

I downloaded a function to simplify Matrix creation in LaTeX. The function works quite good.

I am getting the error:

:herman>vi junk.tex
Error detected while processing /home/herman/.gvimrc:
line  274:
E488: Trailing characters: #:inoremap CreateMatrix():herman>

While the function works fine, this error is annoying me for some time.
Here is the function.

```
 #:inoremap <buffer><expr><m-i>CreateMatrix()
    function! CreateMatrix(rows, ...) abort
      let save_pos=getpos(".")
      let cols = a:0 ? a:1 : 3
      let matrix = ['\begin{pmatrix}']
      call extend(matrix, repeat([repeat('<++> & ', cols - 1) . '<++>\\'], a:rows))
      call add(matrix, '\end{pmatrix}')
      call append(line('.') - 1, matrix)
      call setpos('.', save_pos)
    endfunction
    command! -nargs=+ Matrix silent call CreateMatrix(<f-args>)
```

Comment: What does #: do? If I remove that, it don't get an error.

Comment: @ArjenDijkstra : Then I get the message: No mapping found and the Matrix command (run as , for example, Matrix 2 2) will stop working.

Comment: Remove the ` #:` at the beginning. The `#` has nothing to do here and is probably a copypasta artifact. The `:` is unnecessary in a script.

Comment: @romaini : excellent suggestion. I editted the line manually and removed the old one. Did not include the #, neither the :. The Matrix script works fine. I still get an error "No mapping found. When I open any file with VIM. That might be easier to fix. Thanks!

Comment: @romaini : Here is the problem line. If I comment it out I do not get the "No mapping found error". But I without that line the Matrix macro would not work: inoremap <buffer><expr><m-i>CreateMatrix()

Comment: @romainl : I fixed it!. Add a space between <m-i> and CreateMatrix(). Again, thank you very much!. You made my day.